# border-bottom bigger than the text

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. My border-bottom appears longer than the text it underlines and I just want it to fit right under with the same length as the text.
You can see in the picture how it looks:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xifjB.png)

I tried everything I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions would be great ! Thank you

Here is my code :

```
.navigation {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 40px;

li.active-link>a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: $accent-color;

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

}

 li {
  position: relative;

  &:hover > a {
    color: #1836a9;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #1836a9;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1836a9;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    display: inline
  }
    }

a {
  display: inline;
}
  }

  .has-dropdown {

&.active {
  > a {
    position: relative;
  }

  > ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: post your html, too so that we have a [mcve]

Comment: Do you have padding ? in  the li or a ?

Comment: @ElDanielo   There is padding, when I remove it, it works but the menu items are too close to each other now!

Comment: .navigation-first-tier {
    position: relative;

    > li {
      display: inline-block;

      > a {
        padding: 10px 10px;

      }

Comment: @Jean-LucB replace it with margin.

Answer (score 1):

replace your `padding` on the `a` elements with `margin` (same values, but margin instead of padding)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! It was just changing the padding to a margin and it worked perfectly, thank you for your help it did help me figure out what was wrong.